# Efficient way to take determinant of an n! x n! matrix in Maple

Tags: algorithm, permutation, maple, determinants

I have a large matrix, n! x n!, for which I need to take the determinant. For each permutation of n, I associate

- a vector of length 2n (this is easy computationally)
- a polynomial of in 2n variables (a product of linear factors computed recursively on n)

The matrix is the evaluation matrix for the polynomials at the vectors (thought of as points). So the sigma,tau entry of the matrix (indexed by permutations) is the polynomial for sigma evaluated at the vector for tau.

***Example***: For `n=3`, if the `i`th polynomial is `(x1 - 4)(x3 - 5)(x4 - 4)(x6 - 1)` and the `j`th point is `(2,2,1,3,5,2)`, then the `(i,j)`th entry of the matrix will be `(2 - 4)(1 - 5)(3 - 4)(2 - 1) = -8`. Here `n=3`, so the points are in `R^(3!) = R^6` and the polynomials have `3!=6` variables.

My goal is to determine whether or not the matrix is nonsingular.

---

My approach right now is this:

- the function `point` takes a permutation and outputs a vector
- the function `poly` takes a permutation and outputs a polynomial
- the function `nextPerm` gives the next permutation in lexicographic order

The abridged pseudocode version of my code is this:

```
B := [];
P := [];
w := [1,2,...,n];
while w <> NULL do
  B := B append poly(w);
  P := P append point(w);
  w := nextPerm(w);
od;

// BUILD A MATRIX IN MAPLE
M := Matrix(n!, (i,j) -> eval(B[i],P[j]));

// COMPUTE DETERMINANT IN MAPLE
det := LinearAlgebra[Determinant]( M );

// TELL ME IF IT'S NONSINGULAR
if det = 0 then return false;
else return true; fi;
```

I'm working in Maple using the built in function `LinearAlgebra[Determinant]`, but everything else is a custom built function that uses low level Maple functions (e.g. `seq`, `convert` and `cat`).

My problem is that this takes too long, meaning I can go up to `n=7` with patience, but getting `n=8` takes days. Ideally, I want to be able to get to `n=10`.

Does anyone have an idea for how I could improve the time? I'm open to working in a different language, e.g. Matlab or C, but would prefer to find a way to speed this up within Maple.

I realize this might be hard to answer without all the gory details, but the code for each function, e.g. `point` and `poly`, is already optimized, so the real question here is if there is a faster way to take a determinant by building the matrix on the fly, or something like that.

---

UPDATE: Here are two ideas that I've toyed with that don't work:

1. I can store the polynomials (since they take a while to compute, I don't want to redo that if I can help it) into a vector of length `n!`, and compute the points on the fly, and plug these values into the permutation formula for the determinant:

   [image: permutation determinant formula]

   The problem here is that this is `O(N!)` in the size of the matrix, so for my case this will be `O((n!)!)`. When `n=10`, `(n!)! = 3,628,800!` which is way to big to even consider doing.
2. Compute the determinant using the LU decomposition. Luckily, the main diagonal of my matrix is nonzero, so this is feasible. Since this is `O(N^3)` in the size of the matrix, that becomes `O((n!)^3)` which is much closer to doable. The problem, though, is that it requires me to store the whole matrix, which puts serious strain on memory, nevermind the run time. So this doesn't work either, at least not without a bit more cleverness. Any ideas?

Comment: What domain are the coefficients of your polynomials, and the evaluation points, from? Your examples show integers - is that a simplification or is it actually the case?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear to me if your problem is space or time. Obviously the two trade back and forth. If you only wish to know if the determinant is positive or not, then you definitely should go with `LU` decomposition. The reason is that if `A = LU` with `L` lower triangular and `U` upper triangular, then

```
det(A) = det(L) det(U) = l_11 * ... * l_nn * u_11 * ... * u_nn
```

so you only need to determine if any of the main diagonal entries of `L` or `U` is `0`.

To simplify further, use Doolittle's algorithm, where `l_ii = 1`. If at any point the algorithm breaks down, the matrix is singular so you can stop. Here's the gist:

```
for k := 1, 2, ..., n do {
  for j := k, k+1, ..., n do {
    u_kj := a_kj - sum_{s=1...k-1} l_ks u_sj;
  }
  for i = k+1, k+2, ..., n do {
    l_ik := (a_ik - sum_{s=1...k-1} l_is u_sk)/u_kk;
  }
}
```

The key is that you can compute the `i`th row of `U` and the `i`th column of `L` at the same time, and you only need to know the previous row/column to move forward. This way you parallel process as much as you can and store as little as you need. Since you can compute the entries `a_ij` as needed, this requires you to store two vectors of length `n` while generating two more vectors of length `n` (rows of `U`, columns of `L`). The algorithm takes `n^2` time. You might be able to find a few more tricks, but that depends on your space/time trade off.

Comment: This looks like I have to store both of the LU matrices to compute them. I don't have enough memory for that. Is there another way?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I've followed your problem; is it (or does it reduce to) the following?

You have two vectors of n numbers, call them `x` and `c`, then the matrix element is product over `k` of `(x_k+c_k)`, with each row/column corresponding to distinct orderings of `x` and `c`?

If so, then I believe the matrix will be singular whenever there are repeated values in either `x` or `c`, since the matrix will then have repeated rows/columns.  Try a bunch of Monte Carlo's on a smaller `n` with distinct values of `x` and `c` to see if that case is in general non-singular - it's quite likely if that's true for 6, it'll be true for 10.

As far as brute-force goes, your method:

1. Is a non-starter
2. Will work much more quickly (should be a few seconds for `n=7`), though instead of LU you might want to try SVD, which will do a much better job of letting you know how well behaved your matrix is.

Comment: No. One vector has points in R^(n!), e.g. `(2,2,1,3,5,2)`, and the other has polynomials in n! variables, e.g. `(x1 - 4)(x3 - 5)(x4 - 4)(x6 - 1)`. The matrix is the evaluation of the polynomials at the points, e.g. the entry for the example would be `(2 - 4)(1 - 5)(3 - 4)(2 - 1)`.

Comment: Monte Carlo doesn't help at all. I have a specific set of point vectors and a specific set of polynomial vectors and I need to know if the evaluation matrix for those polynomials at those points is nonsingular. You can't Monte Carlo that, at least not as far as I know.